# What is better: link to a GameObject or to a Class in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Example: GameObject A has a script attached to it called MakeItRain. Inside that script is a public void Drizzle();

GameObject B also has a script and wants to tell MakeItRain to do Drizzle();

Inside the script of GameObject B, I can do this:

```
public GameObject makeitrain;
```

and then I have to use GetComponent to reach Drizzle(); in my code.
In the inspector, I drop GameObject A into the slot of makeitrain and I'm done.

However, I *could also* do this in the script of GameObject B:

```
public MakeItRain makeitrain;
```

and then just call `makeitrain.Drizzle();` in my code of GameObject B's script, without GetComponent.

In both cases, in the Inspector, I have to drag and drop GameObject A into the slot of GameObject B.

Is there a difference or reason why I should definitely not do the last option? I understand that the first method gives me more flexibility because I could call other components of GameObject A as well and not just the script's stuff. Just wondering if there is any other rationale for not doing the second method.

Comment: It depends purely on whether your client code (Script A, I supposed) wants to work directly with the game object or the game object's attached script component. One thing the 2nd method offers not offered by the 1st is strong typing. I personally try to avoid too many "spaghetti" cross-object/script/component references between vanilla GameObjects; strong typing can help here.

Comment: On a related note: if you know which `MakeItRain` component you want to use, you can wire this up in a `void Reset() {..}` to get it to happen automatically in the editor. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Reset.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer depends if you need to call any function or use variable from the `MakeItRain` script.

If you don't need to to call any function in the `MakeItRain` script or access any variables from it then it is better to use GameObject as the reference. Also, if what you need to do is activate, de-active, rotate the GameObject then use the GameObject as reference.

On the other hand, if you need to be able to call a function such as `Drizzle` or access a variable from the `MakeItRain` script from *multiple places*, then you need to use the `MakeItRain` reference. At this time, it doesn't make sense to use the GameObject  reference since by using it, it's required to use `GetComponent` every-time you need to call a function or access a variable from the `MakeItRain` script attached to it.

Finally, when using the `MakeItRain` script to reference your object, you can directly and easily access the GameObject it is attached to without using the `makeitrain.gameObject`. This doesn't require the use of the `GetComponent` function.

> Just wondering if there is any other rationale for not doing the
>   second method.

Performance issue due to the required use of the `GetComponent` function  is the reason. Using it once in the `Start` or `Awake` function and initializing your `MakeItRain` variable is better.

For example, this is better:

```
public MakeItRain makeitrain;

void Start()
{
    makeitrain = GetComponent<MakeItRain>();
}

void Update()
{
    makeitrain.Drizzle();
}
```

than this:

```
public GameObject makeitrain;

void Update()
{
    makeitrain.GetComponent<MakeItRain>().Drizzle();
}
```

And should be used to avoid having to search for the component on the native side *every frame*.

Answer (score 0):

Using `MakeItRain` and explicitly defining the type is better than using `GameObject`.

As @hacksalot commented, using **`MakeItRain` offers strong typing**. One of the benefits of this is related to your comment:

> In both cases, in the Inspector, I have to drag and drop GameObject A
>   into the slot of GameObject B.

If you explicitly set the public variable type to `MakeItRain` rather than `GameObject`, it is not possible to drag and drop a GameObject A into the slot of GameObject B *unless* GameObject A is has a script of the correct type. This gives you a **compile-time/editor-time check that you are linking to the correct GameObject in the Unity Editor inspector**.

Also, while not necessarily so, **using `GameObject` references often encourages messier code**, whether because of unnecessary chaining of methods together (e.g. `GetComponent`) just because the type wasn't specified, or because it adds a bit of friction to writing & using helper methods. Consider even in a simple example which one reads better:

`makeitrain.Drizzle()`

`makeitrain.GetComponent<MakeItRain>().Drizzle()`

---

> I understand that the first method gives me more flexibility because I
>   could call other components of GameObject A as well and not just the
>   script's stuff.

Note that you still have the flexibility to access `GameObject`, it's just a bit more verbose (which is one downside of this approach):

```
public MakeItRain makeitrain;

void Start()
{
    makeitrain.gameObject.SetActive(false)
}
```

However, you'll likely be using helper methods anyway (for anything more than basic calls), or even wrapper methods (which are inconvenient to write but sometimes helpful for readability).

In most cases, the benefits of linking to the class rather than the `GameObject` outweigh the downsides.

Answer (score -1):

If u don't want to use `GetComponent()`, you can simply use `SendMeassage()`, like this

```
public Gameobject makeItRain;
void Start(){
    makeitrain.SendMeassage("Drizzle");
}
```

Another way to link a script is that use `FindObjectOfType()`, which do not need to drag and drop `GameObject` into the slot, here is the sample

```
void Start(){
    MakeItRain makeitrain = FindObjectOfType("MakeItRain");
}
```

Also you can use `Gameobject.Find()` to link a `GameObject` instead of dragging into slot, but I don't recommand this way, it cost a lot performance since you need to find every single GameObject in scene.

Comment: Isn't `SendMeassage` slower due to reflection? And and how can you differentiate which component to get with `FindObjectOfType` when you have multiple instances of one component?

Comment: BTW you either have to typecast `(MakeItRain)FindObjectOfType("MakeItRain");` or better use the generic version `FindObjectOfType<MakeItRain>();` still PassetCronUs is right and this doesn't work if you have more than one component of the type in your scene - which is the case in OP's question

Comment: Aside from the fact that SendMessage is slow it will silently stop working when you decided to rename Drizzle() method to something else. The best analogy I saw about SendMessage on Unity forums: SendMessage is when the devil beats the drums for all the ugliest beasts to come out.